# Сортировка Map на java c помощью TreeMap

Tags: java

Есть map<String, Set>, как ее отсортировать? Знаю, что можно использовать структуру TreeMap, только как применять - вопрос.

Comment: TreeMap из коробки отсортированный будет.

Answer (score -1):

решение оказалось в две строки)

```
Map<String, Set<Doc>> dictionary = new TreeMap<String, Set<Doc>>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
dictionary.putAll(dictionary);
```

Теперь вопрос в другом как производить поиск в словаре...

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! если у вас появился новый вопрос, задайте его, пожалуйста, с помощью кнопки «[задать вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)» в правом верхнем углу страницы; если нужно указать контекст, дайте ссылку на этот вопрос.

Comment: Нет абсолютно понимания о том, что вы хотите сделать... Зачем сортировать Map по ключу, если вы потом хотите делать поиск по ней? В Map **УЖЕ** поиск по ключу занимает O(1). Выражайтесь, пожалуйста, адекватно. Что и как вы хотите сделать. Что за **Set** вы храните в качестве значения? **Set<Object>**? И что вы собрались там в этом Object искать? Если вам нужно сортировать не по ключу (как сделали вы), а по значению, то напишите свой собственный **Comparator**